# Why do strings select vacuum solutions of Einstein Field Equations as their natural backgrounds?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, string-theory, vacuum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I have a conceptual issue here. The action of a bosonic string in some curved metric $g_{\mu\nu}(X)$ is given by
$$S[X] = -\frac{1}{4\pi \alpha'} \int d\sigma d\tau \: g_{\mu\nu}(X)\: \partial^\alpha X^\mu \partial_\alpha X^\nu\tag{13.3}$$
The book I'm reading (A primer on String Theory by Volker Schomerus) states that the Energy Momentum Tensor on the World Sheet satisfies
$$T_{-+} \sim -\alpha' R_{\mu\nu} (X) \partial_- X^\mu \partial_+ X^\nu + \dots\tag{p.129}$$
up to leading order in $\alpha'$.
If we want to construct Virasoro modes on this background, we need the trace of the Energy Momentum Tensor to vanish, so we require
$$R_{\mu\nu} (X) = 0.$$
This means, that the background is a vacuum solution to the Einstein Field Equations. This implies a vanishing energy momentum tensor on the target space:
$$T_{\mu\nu} = 0.$$
But here's my conceptual problem: The target space is not a vacuum; it contains the string. The string has energy and it can have excitations that give rise to massive particles. So how can the energy momentum tensor be zero?

Answer (score 0):

OP's conceptual issue seems to be essentially a combination of 3 things:

1. The conformal/Weyl symmetry must be maintained in a consistent string theory, i.e. the beta functions must vanish. This is discussed in any good textbook on string theory.
2. The quantum Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ [and hence the notion of energy] is shifted from the Virasoro constraints [which are the Fourier-modes of the [SEM tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor)] by a normal ordering constant $a$. [Also note that the bosonic string discussed here has a tachyon, which ultimately dooms the theory.]
3. Perturbation of the path integral with the Polyakov action generate a coherent background of graviton vertex operators, cf. Refs. 1 & 2.

References:

1. J. Polchinski, *String Theory* Vol. 1, 1998; Section 3.7 p. 108.
2. D. Tong, [*Lectures on String Theory*](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html); Chapter 7 p. 159.